# Node.js HTTPS Request for Quandl API

Tags: json, node.js, https, ibm-cloud, quandl

I am using IBM Bluemix to make a web service for a school project.

My project needs to request JSON data from two APIs, for use in the project.

The first one is a `http.request`, which I executed just fine. For the second one, however, I need a `https.request` - and that is where the trouble comes from.

I don't know how to `get` a JSON through a `https` request. I've been trying to adapt the code for the `http` one, but my efforts have rendered useless.

How can I request a JSON via `https`?

Here is my `.js`file:

```js
// Hello.
//
// This is JSHint, a tool that helps to detect errors and potential
// problems in your JavaScript code.
//
// To start, simply enter some JavaScript anywhere on this page. Your
// report will appear on the right side.
//
// Additionally, you can toggle specific options in the Configure
// menu.

function main() {
  return 'Hello, World!';
}

main();/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// HTTP request - duas alternativas
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

//HTTPS request
var https = require('https');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');


// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

//chama o express, que abre o servidor
var express = require('express');

// create a new express server 
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    // print a message when the server starts listening
    console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});


app.get('/home1', function (req,res) {
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function (res2) {
        var body = '';
        res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res2.on('end', function () {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var CotacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["variacao"];
            var CotacaoEuro = json["euro"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoEuro = json["euro"]["variacao"];
            var Atualizacao = json["atualizacao"];
   
   obj=req.query; 
   
   DolarUsuario=obj['dolar'];
   RealUsuario=Number(obj['dolar'])*CotacaoDolar;
   
   EuroUsuario=obj['euro'];
   RealUsuario2=Number(obj['euro'])*CotacaoEuro;
   
   Oi=1*VariacaoDolar;
   Oi2=1*VariacaoEuro;
   
   if (VariacaoDolar<0) {
   recomend= "Recomenda-se, portanto, comprar dólares.";
   }
   
   else if (VariacaoDolar=0){
    recomend="";
   }
   
   else {
    recomend="Recomenda-se, portanto, vender dólares.";
      }
      
   if (VariacaoEuro<0) {
   recomend2= "Recomenda-se, portanto, comprar euros.";
   }
   
   else if (VariacaoEuro=0){
    recomend2="";
   }
   else {
    recomend2="Recomenda-se,portanto, vender euros.";
      }   
      
   res.render('cotacao_response.jade', {
                    'CotacaoDolar':CotacaoDolar,
      'VariacaoDolar':VariacaoDolar,
      'Atualizacao':Atualizacao,
      'RealUsuario':RealUsuario,
      'DolarUsuario':DolarUsuario,
      'CotacaoEuro':CotacaoEuro,
      'VariacaoEuro':VariacaoEuro,
      'RealUsuario2':RealUsuario2,
      'recomend':recomend,
      'recomend2':recomend2,
      'Oi':Oi,
      'Oi2':Oi2
            });
   
  app.get('/home2', function (req,res) {
    https.get('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BCB/432.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY', function (res3) {
        var body = '';
        res3.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
  res3.on('end', function () {
            var x=json.dataset.data[0][1];
      console.log("My JSON is "+x); });
      
    });
    });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Not that relevant here, but check you have imported https module twice in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your https.get should work as set up. There were a few other issues with your code that caused it to break, which I'm outlining below with explanations:

#### 1. Potentially incorrect nesting of the `/home2` route

Your declaration of the `/home2` route was inside the declaration of your `/home1` route. It is likely that you meant it to be outside. I've fixed this (and also fixed some indentation) in the code below.

#### 2. json is undefined in the `/home2` route's `https.get` callback

The variable `json` is not defined before use in the `https.get` callback function. You will need a line similar to the one you have in the `http.get` callback: `var json = JSON.parse(body);`.

**Here's the fixed code for the routes**

```
app.get('/home1', function (req,res) {
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function (res2) {
        var body = '';

        res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res2.on('end', function () {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var CotacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["variacao"];
            var CotacaoEuro = json["euro"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoEuro = json["euro"]["variacao"];
            var Atualizacao = json["atualizacao"];

            obj=req.query; 

            DolarUsuario=obj['dolar'];
            RealUsuario=Number(obj['dolar'])*CotacaoDolar;

            EuroUsuario=obj['euro'];
            RealUsuario2=Number(obj['euro'])*CotacaoEuro;

            Oi=1*VariacaoDolar;
            Oi2=1*VariacaoEuro;

            if (VariacaoDolar<0) {
                recomend= "Recomenda-se, portanto, comprar dólares.";
            }

            else if (VariacaoDolar=0){
                recomend="";
            }

            else {
                recomend="Recomenda-se, portanto, vender dólares.";
            }

            if (VariacaoEuro<0) {
                recomend2= "Recomenda-se, portanto, comprar euros.";
            }

            else if (VariacaoEuro=0){
                recomend2="";
            }
            else {
                recomend2="Recomenda-se,portanto, vender euros.";
            }

            res.render('cotacao_response.jade', {
               'CotacaoDolar':CotacaoDolar,
               'VariacaoDolar':VariacaoDolar,
               'Atualizacao':Atualizacao,
               'RealUsuario':RealUsuario,
               'DolarUsuario':DolarUsuario,
               'CotacaoEuro':CotacaoEuro,
               'VariacaoEuro':VariacaoEuro,
               'RealUsuario2':RealUsuario2,
               'recomend':recomend,
               'recomend2':recomend2,
               'Oi':Oi,
               'Oi2':Oi2
            });
        });
    });
});

app.get('/home2', function (req,res) {
    https.get('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BCB/432.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY', function (res3) {
        var body = '';

        res3.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res3.on('end', function () {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var x=json.dataset.data[0][1];
            console.log("My JSON is "+x);
            res.send('done https: JSON result: '+x);
        });
    });
});
```

#### Final note

You added your API key in the https URL. I would recommend changing the key, if sensitive information is involved.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTPS server and client API is almost identical to the HTTP API.In fact, the client API is the same, and the HTTPS server only differs in that it needs a certificate file.

Starting the server

To start the HTTPS server, you need to read the private key and certificate. Note that readFileSync is used in this case, since blocking to read the certificates when the server starts is acceptable:

```
// HTTPS
var https = require('https');
// read in the private key and certificate
var pk = fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem');
var pc = fs.readFileSync('./certificate.pem');
var opts = { key: pk, cert: pc };
// create the secure server
var serv = https.createServer(opts, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  res.end();
});
// listen on port 443
serv.listen(443, '0.0.0.0');
```

Note that on Linux, you may need to run the server with higher privileges to bind to port 443. Other than needing to read a private key and certificate, the HTTPS server works like the HTTP server.